# Ruby find atrribute in array of Objects with highest/lowest occurence and return attribute

Tags: ruby

Hello I am wondering if anyone may be able to give some assistance with two functions I am working on for a Ruby project. I have an array of Objects, and I need to get a certain attribute with the highest and lowest occurrence in each function respectively.

So far I have this, which works, but seems a bit too verbose:

```
def most_visited_port(time)

    most_visited_port_name = ""
    most_visited = 0
    ending_port_array = []

    @ships.each do |ship|
        ending_port_array << ship.ending_port
        most_visited = ending_port_array.sort.max_by { |v| ending_port_array.count(v) } != ending_port_array.sort.reverse.max_by { |v| ending_port_array.count(v) } ? false : ending_port_array.max_by { |v| ending_port_array.count(v) }
    end


    @ships.each do |ship|
        if time.to_date === ship.time_arrived.to_date && ship.ending_port == most_visited
            most_visited_port_name = ship.ending_port_name
        end
    end

    pp most_visited_port_name

end

def least_visited_port(time)
    least_visited_port_name = ""
    least_visited = 0
    ending_port_array = []

    @ships.each do |ship|
        ending_port_array << ship.ending_port
        least_visited = ending_port_array.sort.min_by { |v| ending_port_array.count(v) } != ending_port_array.sort.reverse.min_by { |v| ending_port_array.count(v) } ? false : ending_port_array.min_by { |v| ending_port_array.count(v) }
    end


    @ships.each do |ship|
        if time.to_date === ship.time_arrived.to_date && ship.ending_port == least_visited
            least_visited_port_name = ship.ending_port_name
        end
    end

    pp least_visited_port_name
end
```

Here is a sample of the array of Objects format:

```
[#<FleetShip:0x0000000108444450
  @average_speed=46.02272727272727,
  @beginning_port=7,
  @beginning_port_name="Summermill",
  @distance=81.0,
  @ending_port=3,
  @ending_port_name="Seamont",
  @id=0,
  @ship_name="Alpha",
  @time_arrived=2016-06-12 08:05:36 -0500,
  @time_left=2016-06-12 06:20:00 -0500>,
 #<FleetShip:0x0000000108444400
  @average_speed=32.01932579334578,
  @beginning_port=7,
  @beginning_port_name="Summermill",
  @distance=81.0,
  @ending_port=3,
  @ending_port_name="Seamont",
  @id=1,
  @ship_name="Sea Ghost",
  @time_arrived=2016-06-12 11:07:47 -0500,
  @time_left=2016-06-12 08:36:00 -0500>]
```

But could anyone give some assistance on a possibly simpler or more concise way to pull it off?

Comment: Try something like this: `@ships.group_by(&:ending_port).values.max_by(&:length)` this will give you the most visited port and all the ships that ended there. Can do the same thing with `min_by` for least visited port. Hope this gets you a bit further.

Comment: Please edit show the desired result for your sample array. Showing desired results for examples is generally helpful to readers, even if you think they are obvious.

Comment: @maxpleaner  There's also [minmax_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-minmax_by).

Answer (score 2):

For fun, you could use `each_with_object` to build a hash of `ending_port` values and their frequency, and then retrieve the most frequent.

I'm going to use a much simpler example.

```rb
A = Struct.new(:b)

c = [A.new(3), A.new(2), A.new(1), A.new(3), A.new(1), A.new(3), A.new(3)]

most_freq_b = c.each_with_object({}) { |x, h| 
  h[x.b] ||= 0
  h[x.b] += 1 
}.max_by(&:last).first
# => 3
```

This does not account for situations where more than one value for `b` occurs equal numbers of times. We can tweak it though, to accomplish this.

```rb
A = Struct.new(:b)

c = [A.new(3), A.new(2), A.new(1), A.new(3), A.new(1)]

freq = c.each_with_object({}) { |x, h| 
  h[x.b] ||= 0
  h[x.b] += 1 
}

highest_freq = freq.values.max

most_freq_b = freq.select { |_, v| v == highest_freq }.keys
# => [3, 1]
```

Alternatively, we can provide a default value of `0` for the hash, simplifying part of the code.

```
freq = c.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x, h| 
  h[x.b] += 1 
}
```

Comment: `freq` could also be defined using `tally` (`c.map(&:b).tally`)

Comment: Using `tally` does make the code more compact but it has the disadvantage that, unlike the proposed solution, it creates a temporary array (`c.map(&:b)`).